# Active Record, count of grandchild association record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I've got:

```
class Town < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :citizens
end

class Citizen < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :town
  has_many :cars
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :citizen
end
```

Using ActiveRecord, what is the simplest way I can get a count of cars in the town?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your models you can define a through association.

```
class Town < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :citizens
  has_many :cars , :through => :citizens
end
```

And query like this.

```
@town.cars.count
```

or

```
Town.find("town id").cars.count
```